# In Android Kotlin, the assertNotNull causes the unit test to not run

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

In Android Studio I created androidTest package and added a `TestClass`.
The `@BeforeClass` function is required to be static, 
so I have to add `@JvmStatic` and put it in the `companion object`.

But if put `assertNotNull()` inside the `companion object` it will show “Empty test suite” when running the test, and the test does not run.
But it does see the `"+++ +++ initBeforeTest()"` log which is placed before the assertXXX statement.

```
+++ +++ initBeforeTest()
++ +++ afterTest()

Client not ready yet..
Started running tests
Tests ran to completion.

Empty test suite.
```

If I comment out the `assertNotNull()` in the `@BeforeClass` function, which is inside the companion, the test will run as expected.

```
+++ +++ initBeforeTest()
++ +++ afterTest()

Client not ready yet..
Started running tests

java.lang.AssertionError: test assertNotNull
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
```

Any idea why the assertNotNull() (actually all assertXXX functions) causes the test not to run?

Gradle has:

```
testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12”
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1”
```

test class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class TestClass {

    companion object {
        @BeforeClass @JvmStatic
        fun beforeTest() {
            Log.e("+++","+++ +++ initBeforeTest()")
            // if comment out this assertNotNull(), the test will run
            assertNotNull("test assertNotNull", null) //<== causes "Empty test suite."
        }

        @AfterClass @JvmStatic
        fun afterTest() {

        }
    }

    @Test
    fun test1() {
        assertNotNull("test assertNotNull", null)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that if the method you've annotated with `@BeforeClass` fails, the Junit Runner will not execute the rest of the suite.

Because your assertion (`assertNotNull("test assertNotNull", null)`) fails, an exception is thrown (actually an `AssertionError`) causing the suite setup to fail. This in turn causes the test runner to assume it has no tests. That's why removing the failing assertion will cause the tests to run (because the setup succeeds).

If you change your assertion in the setup to this, I suspect it will pass:

```
assertNull("test assertNull", null)
```

**Edit**: To be more clear, when you use `assertNotNull` you are telling Junit that the value provided *cannot be null*, and in your case it is. The first argument to `assertNotNull` ("test assertNotNull") is a message that will be incorporated into the failure message (as you can see in the output you've provided). The second argument (null, in this case) is the thing that cannot be null.

Comment: you're right, if change to org.junit.Assert.assertNull("test assertNull", null), it will pass.  Using 'null' with the assertNotNull() was intended to see the assert will kick in if the result is null (in real code the 'null' is actually a object calculated at runtime).   Strange though, expecting it should throw if the assert fail. thanks a lot!